# find directory or file that ends in any 3 characters

Tags: linux, grep, ls, filenames

i am trying to find directory or file that ends in any 3 characters with using

```
ls -l /etc | grep ???$
```

and this doesnt work,,

what should I type to find any directory of files that ends with 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 ... characters?

Comment: Are your three characters _any_ characters, or three specific ones? If they are any characters, then the question is the same as "find names that are _at least three characters long_". Right?

Comment: Do you mean that the rest of the file name may contain non-characters, while you want the end of the files to contain 3 to 7 characters? How do you define a non-character? Is that sequence of bytes forming valid characters in the current locale encoding? See also [How to create string with invalid unicode characters, in Zsh?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/247731) for other interpretations

Answer (score 2):

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{3}$'
```

This will find file or directory names in `/etc/` that are **exactly** 3 characters long.

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{3,}$'
```

And this will find files or directories in `/etc/` that are a **minimum** of 3 characters long.

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{3,7}$'
```

And this will find files or directories in `/etc` that are anywhere from 3 to 7 characters long.

The `-maxdepth 1` prevents find from searching sub-directories of /etc.

If you want to restrict the match to directories only, add `-type d` after the `-maxdepth 1`. For regular files, use `-type f`.

If you intend to do anything with the files/dirs found, you can use find's `-exec` option.  e.g.

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{3,7}$' -exec du -sch {} +
```

or `xargs` (but use NUL separators to avoid problems with spaces, newlines, etc in filenames).  This allows you to use any tool that can process NUL-separated input in the pipeline before `xargs`.  e.g.:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep  -regex '.*/.{3,7}$' -print0 | 
  head -z -n 10 |
  xargs -0r ls -ld
```

Answer (score 1):

To list the names in a single directory (i.e. not recursively) that contain at least three characters, you may use any of the globbing patterns `*???`, `???*` or `*???*`.  Each `?` matches a single character, while `*` matches any number of characters.

To list such names under `/etc` with `ls`:

```
ls -ld /etc/*???
```

or simply,

```
printf '%s\n' /etc/*???
```

If you want to list the names that end in three *specific* characters (e.g. `xyz`), then use `*xyz` as the pattern.

To search for such names recursively, you may (in `bash`) use `shopt -s globstar` to enable the `**` globbing pattern (matches recursively down into subdirectories) and then...

```
ls -ld /etc/**/*???
```

The `**` pattern is enabled by default in the `zsh` shell.

To *do* something with these names (other than just calling `ls`), use a loop:

```
shopt -s globstar
for pathname in /etc/**/*???; do
    # use "$pathname" to do something
done
```

In the `dash` shell or plain `sh`, the equivalent of this loop would be

```
find /etc -name '*???' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # use "$pathname" to do something
    done' sh {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Your use of `grep` shows that you are confusing regular expressions with filename globbing patterns.  In a regular expression, a dot (`.`) matches any one single character, while `?` matches just the character `?` (at least in basic regular expressions, which is what `grep` uses by default).

Filename patterns are also always anchored, so there's no need to explicitly anchor the pattern with `$` as in a regular expression (the pattern must match the complete filename though, so `xyz` matches exactly that name while `*xyz` matches any filename ending in `xyz`).

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Comment: Note that in most shells, `?` also matches on every byte that doesn't form part of valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `find` and filter for the result:

```bsh
find -type f | egrep '3$|4$|5$'
```